# Why did the unit test fail?

Tags: java, spring, unit-testing, junit, tdd

I'm a new developer. Can someone tell me why did the following unit test fail?

Here is UserController.java

```
@RequiredArgsConstructor
@RestController
public class UserController {

private final UserService userService;

@PostMapping(value="/v1/user")
public ResponseEntity<ResponseDto> postUser(@RequestBody UserSaveRequestDto userSaveRequestDto) {
    Long userId = userService.insertUser(userSaveRequestDto);

    return CommonUtil.getResponseEntity(UserResponseDto.builder()
                                                            .userId(userId)
                                                            .build()
                                                            , HttpStatus.OK
                                                            , "회원 등록 완료");
}

}
```

Here is UserControllerTest.java

given(userService.insertUser(userSaveRequestDto)).willReturn(1L); // not working

so ".andExpect(jsonPath("$.data.userId").value("1"))" is fail

Please let me know why given() doesn't work.

```
@WebMvcTest
public class UserControllerTest {

MockMvc mockMvc;

@MockBean // Mock Bean은 Mock과 달리 Container가 관리하도록 빈을 만듬, 일반적으로 MockMvc와 많이씀
UserService userService;

@Autowired
ObjectMapper objectMapper;

@Autowired
private WebApplicationContext ctx;

UserSaveRequestDto userSaveRequestDto;

@BeforeEach
void setUp() {
    mockMvc = MockMvcBuilders.webAppContextSetup(ctx)
        .addFilters(new CharacterEncodingFilter("UTF-8", true))  // 한글 깨짐 처리
        .build();

    userSaveRequestDto = UserSaveRequestDto.builder()
        .userName("test")
        .userPhoneNumber("01026137832")
        .build();
}

@DisplayName("MockMvc를 이용한 postUser slice 테스트")
@Test
public void postUserTest() throws Exception {
    // given
    given(userService.insertUser(userSaveRequestDto)).willReturn(1L); // Controller가 의존하고 있는 Service객체의 행동을 설정 해준다.
    String content = objectMapper.writeValueAsString(userSaveRequestDto); // dto to json

    // when
    ResultActions resultActions = mockMvc.perform(post("/v1/user")
                    .contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
                    .content(content));

    // then
    resultActions
        // ResultActions 객체의 andDo, andExpect, andReturn 메서드 사용
        .andDo(result -> {
            if (result.getResolvedException() != null) {
                result.getResolvedException().printStackTrace();
            }
        })
        .andExpect(status().isOk())
        .andExpect(jsonPath("$.data.userId").value("1"))
        .andExpect(jsonPath("$.message").value("회원 등록 완료"));
    }

 }
```

Comment: This field in controller class missing `private final UserService userService` Autowired annotation

Comment: Thank you for your answer. However, userService dependencies are injected by the @RequiredArgs Constructor.

Comment: Add .andReturn().getResponse().getContentAsString() to the resultAction chain and store the return value in a String variable. Inspect the content of that variable to see the literal String output of your controller. What does it return?